# Struct constructor: "fields must be fully assigned before control is returned to the caller."

Tags: c#, constructor, struct

Here is a struct I am trying to write:

```
  public struct AttackTraits
        {
            public AttackTraits(double probability, int damage, float distance)
            {
                Probability = probability;
                Distance = distance;
                Damage = damage;
            }

            private double probability;
            public double Probability
            {
                get
                {
                    return probability;
                }
                set
                {
                    if (value > 1 || value < 0)
                    {
                        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Probability values must be in the range [0, 1]");
                    }
                    probability = value;
                }
            }

            public int Damage { get; set; }

            public float Distance { get; set; }
        }
```

This results in the following compilation errors:

> The 'this' object cannot be used
>   before all of its fields are assigned
>   to
>
> Field 'AttackTraits.probability' must
>   be fully assigned before control is
>   returned to the caller
>
> Backing field for automatically
>   implemented property
>   'AttackTraits.Damage' must be fully
>   assigned before control is returned to
>   the caller. Consider calling the
>   default constructor from a constructor
>   initializer.
>
> Backing field for automatically
>   implemented property
>   'AttackTraits.Distance' must be fully
>   assigned before control is returned to
>   the caller. Consider calling the
>   default constructor from a constructor
>   initializer.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You're setting the `probability` field through the `Probability` property, but the compiler doesn't know that the property sets the field... so you need to explicitly initialize the probability field itself

```
public AttackTraits(double probability, int damage, float distance)
{
    this.probability = 0;
    Distance = distance;
    Damage = damage;
}
```

Comment: Tried this.  didn't work for me - but I am using auto properties

Comment: The problem with this solution. You don't have the validation benefits of the Probability property. And it doesn't fix everything because you also need to change `Distance` and `Damage` to non-anonymous properties otherwise it will not work. I prefer @Chris-Amelinckx s answer as a better solution.

Comment: struggled with this to make c#7 code backwards compatible: it pops up when you remove existing auto property initializers (for the same reason as in OP code). note that in this case, the actual answer is @thomas comment above (while you cannot have an explicit default constructor on a struct, you can call it in the constructor chain) > could you edit that into your answer, as comments may be removed?

Answer (score 319):

If you see this error on a struct that has an automatic property, just call the parameterless contructor from your parameterized one by doing `: this()` example below:

```
struct MyStruct
{
  public int SomeProp { get; set; }

  public MyStruct(int someVal) : this()
  {
     this.SomeProp = someVal;
  }
}
```

By calling :this() from your constructor declaration you let the base ValueType class initialize all the backing fields for the automatic properties. We cannot do it manually on our constructor because we don't have access to the backing field of an automatic property.
ValueType is the base class of all structs.

Comment: @ChrisAmelinckx just where do you find all those stuff it looks like some kind of someones imagination though only it works for real (:

Comment: This worked, but I don't understand why. Can anyone explain? Why must the parameterless constructor be called first? I'm missing something...

Comment: @DarrenHale when the first line of the constructor is going to execute, for structs it is required that all fields be initialized already.
SomeProp being an automatic property is equivalent to having an explicit 'someProp' field and the get/set methods.
By calling the base parameterless  : this() constructor you guarantee that before the first line of “your logic” in the constructor, all fields have been initialized.

Comment: Well its cool that we have a solution, but why on earth is this workaround needed?

Comment: @Peter, you raise a good point in that this seems like a workaround. My opinion is that this is not a workaround but a complete solution to the issue. Structs are meant to be lightweight representations of application state that get copied over the executing stack. (Every time a value type instance (a struct) is passed into a method a new copy of it is made within the context of that method, as opposed to passing a reference for a class defined object type).

Comment: Because structs are meant to be lightweight we can consider that properties encapsulating field access are overdoing it on structs. Additionally because of the way memory is allocated for structs and how they get copied anytime they are passed, it requires that all fields be assigned immediately upon instantiation. If you do not implement a constructor on a struct, the default constructor takes care of initializing all the fields that are backing automatic properties.

Comment: If we really want to have automatic properties combined with having explicit constructors on a struct (the language supports it after all!), then we must ensure that all fields are assigned at construction time, which means assigning values to all fields or in the case of having automatic properties, enlisting the help of the default constructor (this()) because we cannot directly reach those backing fields.

Comment: My best advice is that structs should be immutable and as such, can implement publicly accessible readonly fields, perhaps naming them with Caps so that they feel like properties, or else as automatic readonly properties but using this technique (preferred).

Comment: In reviewing the issue again today I am glad to see that at least the compilation error message has been improved to say “Backing field for automatically implemented property 'MyStruct.SomeProperty' must be fully assigned before control is returned to the caller. Consider calling the default constructor from a constructor initializer.” This last phrase wasn’t there at some point.

Comment: I wonder what @jonskeet and Mads would think of extending structs constructor spec to automatically call the base parameterless constructor anytime an explicit constructor is implemented.

Comment: @ChrisAmelinckx i understand that they are lightweight but thats no reason for them to force you to call the empty constructor even when you have done what it is complaining about...

Comment: @Peter, currently the only way to directly assign a value to the backing field of an automatic property is to call the base parameterless constructor, which is done by appending : this() to the constructor definition. Once we do that it is happy to compile it. Another way is to avoid automatic properties, declare explicit fields and assign those in your constructor, you won't have to call the base parameterless one.

Answer (score 51):

try to access probability field not accessor. In this case auto-props should work as well.

There is no way for a struct to have parameterless constructor so consider change it to class instead.

Best practise is to use structs only if they are 16 bytes or less and are immutable. So if you are going to change object fields after creating, consider refactoring it to class.

Also, you can change constructor definition to:

```
construct(params) : this()
```

this will remove error as well

Comment: Just FYI, your answer works, but some of your justification is incorrect.  In fact, structs ALWAYS have a parameterless constructors.  Unlike classes, a struct's parameterless constructor cannot be hidden by creating a constructor with parameters.

Comment: @joshua.ewer: they have true, but it's hidden from usage

Comment: Not to belabor this point unnecessarily, but not only is it perfectly legal to call that constructor, but it'll pop up in intellisense like any other constructor.  Can you provide a case where that's not true?

Comment: @joshua.ewer, @vittore - you are always allowed to call that constructor, what you aren't allowed to do is to give your own implementation, but must always go with the default given to you (which assigns `default(AppropriateType)` to all instance fields).

Comment: Thanks alot. Didn't know about the rule on structs!

Comment: @vittore How would one know that the struct is not larger than 16 bytes to retain its struct form.

Comment: @kashif you can calculate it from fields sizes it has.

Comment: @kashif http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3804638/whats-the-size-of-this-c-sharp-struct

Answer (score 2):

Change the line `Probability = probability` to `this.probability = probability`

In the future pick a different naming convention for fields as you do for parameters.  For example, prefix all fields with an underscore, so you can simply call this:

```
_probability = probability;
```

and see easily what's happening.

Comment: Yes, there simply is an ugly name conflict between a parameter and a field.

Answer (score -3):

try to change **struct** to **class** for *AttackTraits*

```
public class AttackTraits
        {
.........
        {
```