# What's the size of this C# struct?

Tags: c#, struct, sizeof

Is it 12 bytes or 16 bytes when stored in a `List<DataPoint>`?

```
public struct DataPoint
{
    DateTime time_utc;
    float value;
}
```

Is there any sizeof function in C#?

Comment: I hope you are aware that each instance of this struct will be boxed when put in a list, so add the space for the pointer.

Comment: @ToxicAvenger: it will *not* be boxed when you put it inside a `List<DataPoint>`. It would be boxed in an `ArrayList` or `List<object>` though.

Comment: This is more specific, but possibly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3361986/how-to-check-the-number-of-bytes-consumed-by-my-strucure

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Take  a look at @Hans Passant's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3361986/how-to-check-the-number-of-bytes-consumed-by-my-strucure) for interesting background on this issue, esp. with regard to the limitations of `Marshal.Sizeof`.

Answer (score 8):

The CLR is free to lay out types in memory as it sees fit. So it's not possible to directly give "the" size.

However, for structures it's possible to restrict the freedom of the CLR using the [StructLayout Attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute.aspx):

- **Auto**: The runtime automatically chooses an appropriate layout.
- **Sequential**: The members of the object are laid out sequentially and are aligned according to the *StructLayoutAttribute.Pack* value.
- **Explicit**: The precise position of each member is explicitly controlled.

The C# compiler automatically applies the **Sequential** layout kind to any struct. The *Pack* value defaults to 4 or 8 on x86 or x64 machines respectively. So the size of your struct is 8+4=12 (both x86 and x64).

---

**Unrelated** from how a type is laid out in memory, it's also possible to marshal a type in .NET using the [Marshal Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.aspx). The marshaller applies several transformations when marshalling a type, so the result is not always the same as the way the CLR laid out the type. (For example, a `bool` takes 1 byte in memory plus alignment, while the marshaller marshals a `bool` to 4 bytes.)

Comment: Note it's possible with the IL `sizeof` instruction to get the "final" CLR size of a struct, taking into account padding and any other alignment operations. See [my blog post](http://lastyearswishes.com/blog/view/50a30d3bd1f1a5234323b198) for how to use it and more differences (note: I wrote a wrapper library that can be called from C#)

Comment: It's 16 on x64 as is, without attributes. `The Pack value defaults to 4 or 8 on x86 or x64 machines respectively`, but then you contradict yourself.

Answer (score 7):

`Marshal.SizeOf()`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y3ybkfb3.aspx

Comment: You could add the solution to his question: 16 bytes (8 bytes + 4 bytes + 4 bytes alignment)

Comment: Marshal.SizeOf() does *not* return the size of a managed struct, only the unmanaged version of it.  Check Steve's answer.

Answer (score 4):

It will be 12 bytes (4 for float, 8 for DateTime);
`Marshal.SizeOf` will return 16 because the default packing is 8 bytes aligned.
[This](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/84519/mastering-structs-in-c/) is a good article on structs and packing.  It gives a full description of whats actually happening.

Answer (score 0):

Try Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(DataPoint))

Answer (score 0):

The following code is based on [this StackOverflow question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8173239/c-getting-size-of-a-value-type-variable-at-runtime):

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Computes the size of the given managed type. Slow, but reliable. Does not give the same result as Marshal.SizeOf
        /// NOTE: this is not the same as what is the distance between these types in an array. That varies depending on alignment.
        /// </summary>
        public static int ComputeSizeOf(Type t)
        {
            // all this just to invoke one opcode with no arguments!
            var method = new DynamicMethod("ComputeSizeOfImpl", typeof(int), Type.EmptyTypes, typeof(Util), false);
            var gen = method.GetILGenerator();
            gen.Emit(OpCodes.Sizeof, t);
            gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
            var func = (Func<int>)method.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<int>));
            return func();
        }
```

I think the question you are probably wondering, is not what is the size of the type but what is the distance between two contiguous elements in the List. This is because alignment can play a role, as mentioned by others.

I believe the solution to that problem would best be achieved using [`Marshal.UnsafeAddrOfPinnedArrayElement()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.unsafeaddrofpinnedarrayelement?view=netframework-4.7.2), but is very difficult to use correctly, particularly because the `List` does not expose publicly the backing array.