# Get the memory size of a value of an F# type

Tags: f#

I am working on some binary serialization and deserialization tools.  For part of the serialization step, I need to store the size of the data structure being written.  For F# specific data types (e.g. discriminated unions, tuples, and records) how can I get the memory size of a value of a type or of the type itself?  Or what is the best way to get the memory size of a value of an F# data type?

For example, given the type:

```
type MyType = {X: int, Y: double}
```

Can I easily get the memory size of `MyType`?  If I have a value of that type (`let x = {X=1; Y=3.4}`) can I get the memory size of `x`?  I'm guessing that for discriminated unions you would have to get the size from a value rather than the type.

Comment: Wouldn't that depend on the serialized representation? What about serializing to e.g. a MemoryStream and then use its size? For further inspiration you might also want to look at https://github.com/nessos/FsPickler and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/207592/getting-the-size-of-a-field-in-bytes-with-c-sharp

Comment: *"for discriminated unions you would have to get the size from a value rather than the type."* Yes, and for `string`, list, array, `BigInteger`, etc. values, as well as composite values that use such types.

Comment: And then, there are circular structures, mutable things that might change between calculation and actual serialization (if multi-threaded) and many more... Mind telling us a bit about your use-case and why none of the existing tools fits your needs?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8173239/c-getting-size-of-a-value-type-variable-at-runtime