# Why can't I use Marshal.SizeOf() to calculate the size of an instance of type ValueTuple?

Tags: c#, .net, valuetuple

Why does the following code:

```
   ValueTuple<double, double> origin = (0.0, 0.0);

   Console.WriteLine($"Size of ValueTuple<double, double>: {Marshal.SizeOf(origin)}");
```

> throw System.ArgumentException: 'Type
>   'System.ValueTuple`2[System.Double,System.Double]' cannot be marshaled
>   as an unmanaged structure; no meaningful size or offset can be computed.'

Comment: Sounds pretty definitive to me. what is the actual problem you are trying to solve

Comment: Unless you're actually planning to send something into the unmanaged world, `Marshal.SizeOf` may as well be replaced with `Random.Next`. It tells you then size of the unmanaged representation of the type, which is only meaningful if you'll create such a thing, and as it says here, you can't create an unmanaged representation of a valuetuple.

Comment: I'm not attempting to marshal a ValueTuple to unmanaged code.  However, the actual motivation is probably controversial.  I have my own implementation of IList<T> called BigList<T> that uses a pool of buffers that are small enough to stay off the Large Object Heap.  This requires knowing the size in bytes of T.  I've been using Marshal.SizeOf() for this purpose.

Comment: To avoid LOH limit, you need managed size of T, not marshalled size of T returned by `Marshall.SizeOf()`, which can be different ([What’s the difference? sizeof and Marshal.SizeOf](https://ericlippert.com/2013/06/13/whats-the-difference-sizeof-and-marshal-sizeof/)). Some workarounds [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47951125/1286670) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8175490/1286670). Also remember that array size is not just *size_of_T \* array_length* but array needs some additional memory (to store array length, dimension, object headers) which is also runtime-dependent.

Comment: I knew that the "managed" and "unmanaged" sizes of T could be different but my situation is limited to simple value types T and my implementation is not particularly sensitive to errors using Marshal.SizeOf().  My buffers are actually arrays of T and I can tell if they end up on LOH.  What I was missing is that I can Emit OpCodes.Sizeof to get the "managed" size.  This fixes my problem and I can now create BigList<T> where T is a ValueTuple.  Thanks!