# Find the size of a type in an array

Tags: c#

I want to find the size of an element in an array like this:

```cs
float[] vertex = { 0.0f, -0.5f,  0.0f };
```

I've already tried this:

```cs
int size = sizeof(vertex.GetType().GetElementType()) // This doesn't work
int size = sizeof(Single); // This works
```

Comment: do you want the size of the array or a specific index

Comment: I just want to have the size of the type. In this case, I want to have the same result as `sizeof(Single);` @SecurityObscurity

Comment: Does this provide the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8173239/c-getting-size-of-a-value-type-variable-at-runtime?

Comment: What is it you are actually trying to accomplish? You can only get the size of unmanaged types, and it is done at compile time, so you cannot use any runtime types. So `sizeof(float)` would be the correct way to do it, or `sizeof(T)` if you have a generic array with unmanaged constraint.