# Unable to compile a struct

Tags: c#

The following code suggests I cannot use implicit properties with a struct:

```
public struct LimitfailureRecord
{
   public LimitfailureRecord(string sampleCode)
   {
      SampleCode = sampleCode;
   }

   public string SampleCode {get; set;}
   {
   }
}
```

It fails to compile, with the error message

> "Backing field for automatically implemented property
>   'blahblah.LimitfailureRecord.SampleCode'
>   must be fully assigned before control is returned to the caller.
>   Consider calling the default constructor from a constructor
>   initializer."

If I change the struct to a class it's fine.
What do I need to do to make this work as a struct? I'd rather not go to the lengths of backing fields (this is a heavily stripped down version of the real code) if I can avoid it.

Comment: Dup: [C#: Struct Constructor: “fields must be fully assigned ..."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534960/c-struct-constructor-fields-must-be-fully-assigned-before-control-is-returne)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With structs you have to call the default constructor in all other constructors:

```
public LimitfailureRecord(string sampleCode) : this()
{
    SampleCode = sampleCode;
}
```

Comment: I get it - so obvious now.

Answer (score 2):

Use a constructor chaining like so:

```
public LimitfailureRecord(string sampleCode)
    : this()
{
    ...
}
```

The reason is the auto-implemented property introduces a (generated) instance field for backing, as described. All instance fields must be assigned to in an instance constructor *of a `struct`*.

Actually the error text you quote describes the fix pretty well.

Something else: If you keep the `set` accessor of your property `public` you will have a mutable struct. Most people agree that mutable structs should be avoided and are "evil" because their copy-by-value semantics and the possibility of mutating an existing struct value (as in `record.SampleCode = "Here's a new string for an old object";`) don't go well together. Check the threads on mutable and immutable structs.

Answer (score 1):

You either need to call the default constructor or change the method name.

So;

```
      public struct LimitfailureRecord
      {
          public void init(string sampleCode)
          {
              SampleCode = sampleCode;
          }

          public string SampleCode { get; set; }
      }
```

Will work or just make the method definition; `LimitfailureRecord(string sampleCode) : this()`

The later is better because it only requires one call to make things work. If you go the init route you have do do `new LimiFfailureRecord` then call `init` after. structs in C# simply require you to call the default constructor, this isn't the case with classes which is why it will compile if you change it to a class.

Comment: The `init` method is mutating the struct. This is not recommended. For example stuff like `someList[idx].init("asdf");` won't work the way one could think, with a mutable struct.