# Using public readonly fields for immutable structs instead of private field/public getter pairs

Tags: c#, .net, field, readonly, getter-setter

This is my first time writing small immutable structs that will be used in extensive geometric calculations. I'm tempted to use `public readonly` fields instead of `private field/public getter` combinations.

```
public struct Vector4
{
    public readonly float Angle, Velocity;

    // As opposed to:
    private float _Angle, _Velocity;
    public float Angle { get { return (this._Angle); } }
    public float Velocity { get { return (this._Velocity); } }

    public Vector4 (float angle, float velocity)
    {
        // Once set in the constructor, instance values will never change.
        this.Angle = angle;
        this.Velocity = velocity;
    }
}
```

It looks a lot cleaner and eliminates an extra layer (the getter). Short of using public fields being bad practice, are there any negative implications to using public readonly fields this way?

Note, we're talking about value types only. Arrays, for example would expose elements to be overwritten by calling code.

**UPDATE:**

Thanks for all the input. It seems that there is no downside to using `public readonly` fields for cases like this where data-binding, etc. is not used. In my benchmarks, execution time dropped by 70% which is a big deal. Targeting .NET 4, I would have expected the compiler to inline getter-only properties. The benchmarks were of course tested in release configuration without the debugger attached.

Comment: As @asawyer pointed out, this is what I have done with structs in the past, though the readonly is an interesting idea.  The idea behind readonly is they can only be set via declaration or the constructor.  Since structs are *supposed* to be immutable, it sounds like a good idea to me.  I hope to hear back from someone that knows what they're talking about to find out if this is a valid thing to do :O

Comment: @asawyer Note that automatic properties cannot be used in the struct constructor as you will immediately get "The 'this' object cannot be used before all of its fields are assigned to". As such, if you need a constructor to assign values to the properties of the struct, non-automatic properties is the way to go.

Comment: In situations like this, I look to the .NET Framework for guidance. Do structures in the Framework use fields or properties?  The answer is properties, so I would tend to follow suit.  The Framework only really uses fields for constants.  All else being equal, properties give the advantage of being able to bind, which fields can't, and also allow you to change an implementation in the future without changing the interface.  Future-proofing doesn't hurt.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I didnt remember that thank you. I usually use static helper functions with private ctors on struts.

Comment: using properties instead of readonly fields are usually done for forward compatibility.

If you later on decide that one of the properties can be calculated, and change it to a property doing the calculation, all existing assemblies that already reference your assembly with the struct needs to be recompiled as well. Additionally, calling a property getter that only returns the value of a private field *might* be inlined into the calling code so it may not incur a call overhead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In pure C# without reflection, there are few reasons to avoid read-only fields in your case, and I probably would opt for read-only fields myself. Most of the general advantages of properties don't really apply here. That said...

Anything that uses reflection to get a list of properties, and acts on those properties, will not work with fields (whether read-only or not) without modification.

In particular, changing properties to fields may cause data binding to stop working. It will continue to compile without any issue, but it will no longer do what you want it to. If you have any such code, or you anticipate such code in the future, you need to keep using properties.

Comment: +1 for mentioning data binding. Not that it applies to my case but how do you see reflection problems with fields? Or did you mean if properties were changed to fields?

Comment: @RaheelKhan Data binding is an example of code using reflection that only looks at properties. `typeof(Vector4).GetProperties()` won't include your read-only fields; for that, `typeof(Vector4).GetFields()` should be used. And if (as is the case with data binding) the call to `GetProperties()` is not in your own code, then you're stuck.

Comment: +1 An excellent answer. In particular, "...[if] you anticipate such code in the future..." - who knows what the future holds? For that reason alone, I would find it hard to justify sacrificing the encapsulation of a property unless there was a pretty serious performance implication. 70% sounds serious, but if the class is only used a few times it is absolutely trivial. Circumstances rule.

Answer (score 7):

Guidelines, such as "Prefer public properties over public fields" are guidelines, not rules.

In *some* cases the *pros* of using fields may outweigh the *cons*. In fact, Rico Mariani did a good job at illustrating one such scenario, which in my opinion looks a lot like yours:

- [Performance Quiz #11: Ten Questions on Value-Based Programming](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ricom/archive/2006/08/31/733887.aspx)
- [Performance Quiz #11: Ten Questions on Value-Based Programming : Solution](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ricom/archive/2006/09/07/performance-quiz-11-ten-questions-on-value-based-programming-solution.aspx)

His main argument for having fields instead of properties was that primitives like `Point`, `Vector` and `Vertex` usually have no illegal values, so there's little or no need for adding the getter/setter layer.

He also makes good arguments for having *mutable* fields, but that's not your case anyway.

But I'd like to add a point myself for you to consider: Will your classes ever be used for data binding? Data binding only works for properties, not fields.

Comment: Thanks for the links. Mutability is not an option in my case since these objects need to be processed heavily using dictionaries, hashsets, etc. And no, this code is not meant to be used for data-binding or any UI scenarios.

Comment: @RaheelKhan Then your situation may be a good candidate for using public readonly fields :)

Answer (score 1):

The .NET Framework Design Guidelines [say about fields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/field):

> DO NOT provide instance fields that are public or protected.

That's a strong statement. It's not an absolute rule, but it's pretty close per the guidelines' [introduction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/):

> There might be situations where good library design requires that you violate these design guidelines. Such cases should be rare, and it is important that you have a clear and compelling reason for your decision.

So what does this mean for your code? A key question is your code's audience. Are you writing a "framework" as the guidelines define it, which is one of the "libraries that extend and interact with the .NET Framework"?

If you're writing a framework, you have constraints that most code doesn't have. Lots of other code will depend on yours, be sensitive to breaking changes, and require binary compatibility to your DLL. This is why properties are important for frameworks. If a later version of a framework needs to add logic to a getter or setter, changing from a field to a property would break binary compatibility.

Most code isn't part of a framework. Dependencies are few and can be easily fixed if there's a simple breaking change. For example, dependent code might use a field in an `out` or `ref` parameter. If later that field is changed to a property so that it can have some logic, it's often no big deal to fix the broken code. The compiler will lead you right to the problem. Similarly, there's no need for binary compatibility. You'll won't ever drop in an updated DLL without also recompiling the dependency.

For non-framework code, a field is preferable if the chance of changing it to a property later is small. Fields are more flexible and properties and in some cases faster.

Answer (score 0):

Auto-properties may help.

```
public struct Vector4
    {
    public float Angle { get; private set; }
    public float Velocity { get; private set; }

    public Vector4(float angle, float velocity) : this()
        {
        // Once set in the constructor, instance values will never change.
        this.Angle = angle;
        this.Velocity = velocity;
        }
    }
```

[Note: updated to make it compile - thanks Lasse V. Karlsen for pointing that out]

Note that this is exactly the same as having a property with a backing field, except that you are letting the compiler choose its name (which will be some 'unutterable' string of characters).

What is it that bothers you about properties? If it is the verbosity, then use an auto property as above. If you are concerned about performance, then have you measured the impact of properties vs. fields?

Interestingly, in his book *CLR via C#*, Jeffrey Richter is fairly "down" on properties, stating that he wishes they had not been included in the CLR. He says he prefers explicit use of getXXX and setXXX methods. He argues that the property syntax is confusing. Personally, having seen Java code which works exactly like that, I prefer the property syntax.

I think it is also worth mentioning that `readonly` can be confusing as well. In this situation it is unambiguous because we are dealing with value types throughout and `readonly` 'does what it says on the tin'. However, had these been reference types, then `readonly` only protects the reference - that is, the field must always reference the same object, but the referenced object itself might be mutated if it is written to allow that. I suspect many inexperienced programmers get tripped up by that subtlety.

Given your measured performance benefit, I think you have a reasonable argument for using public readonly fields, and that is a judgement call. The trade-off is that you are allowing consumers of your type to be tightly coupled with the internals of your struct, essentially sacrificing encapsulation. For such a simple type under controlled conditions and with a proven performance benefit, that may well be justified.

Comment: This does not compile. You cannot set automatic properties in a struct constructor.

Comment: I know about auto-properties and use them generously. In this case however, calculation benchmarks dropped to 30% of the time with readonly fields as opposed to properties. That's a biggie for CPU intensive code.

Comment: @RaheelKhan Did you profile DEBUG build or RELEASE build?

Comment: Release without the debugger attached.

Comment: Why the downvote? Please do leave a comment explaining downvotes so the answers can be improved.

Comment: @RaheelKhan I did, it doesn't compile. You cannot use automatic properties in a struct constructor, hence my -1 vote. You will get a "The 'this' object cannot be used before all of its fields are assigned to" compiler error. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534960/struct-constructor-fields-must-be-fully-assigned-before-control-is-returned-to

Comment: Basically all that is left of this answer is the last paragraph, and that is, in my opinion, more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: Thanks. I made the same mistake in the question itself.

Comment: @RaheelKhan +1 I agree, I wish people would state why they are up/down voting, we would all learn a lot more that way. To be clear, I think the down vote was completely justified as my code had a compilation error in it, the voter should have called me out on that so I could correct it.