# Populate a class with LINQ query

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I need to populate a class using an XML file.

```xml
<Ship>
    <Name>Base Ship</Name>
    <Owner>PG</Owner>
    <Aim>
        <Type>base</Type>
        <Value>10</Value>
        <Last>-1</Last>
    </Aim>
    <Aim>
        <Type>cannon</Type>
        <Value>10</Value>
        <Last>2</Last>
    </Aim>
    <Dodge>
        <Type>base</Type>
        <Value>10</Value>
        <Last>-1</Last>
    </Dodge>
    <EmPower>
        <Type>base</Type>
        <Value>10</Value>
        <Last>-1</Last>
    </EmPower>
</Ship>
```

My problem is how to populate a `Dictionary<string, CustomStruct>`

This is the `struct`:

```
public struct Stat
{
    public int StatValue { get; set; }
    public int StatLast { get; set; }

    public Stat(int statValue, int statLast)
    {
        StatValue = statValue;
        StatLast = statLast;
    }
}
```

My LINQ query looks like this:

```
string loadDataPath = Application.persistentDataPath + "/saveData.xml";
XDocument loadData = XDocument.Load(loadDataPath);

var query = from item in loadData.Elements("Ship")
            select new Ship()
            {
                Name = (string) item.Element("Name"),
                Owner = (string) item.Element("Owner"),
                Aim = item.Elements("Aim") // <-- Here lies the problem.
                // ...
            };
```

For each Aim `XElements` I need to populate the Aim dictionary using the following method:

```
Aim TKey = XML Type
Aim TValue.StatValue = XML Value
Aim TValue.StatLast = XML Last
```

Comment: If you take a look at my updated answer, you will also know why `struct` didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`ToDictionary()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549277(v=vs.110).aspx) extension method to achieve what you want:

```
Aim = item.Elements("Aim").ToDictionary(x => (string)x.Element("Type"), x => new Stat(int.Parse((string)x.Element("Value")), int.Parse((string)x.Element("Last"))))
```

Also, I had to change `struct` to `class` for `Stat`, in order to make it work.

If you want to use `struct` you need to modify it a bit:

```
public struct Stat
{
    public int StatValue { get; set; }
    public int StatLast { get; set; }
    public Stat(int statValue, int statLast) : this()
    {
        StatValue = statValue;
        StatLast = statLast;
    }
}
```

Got this from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5275151/4546874).

Comment: on item.Elements("Aim"):
Cannot convert instance argument type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>'

Comment: @FᴀʀʜᴀɴAɴᴀᴍ Just FYI, in LINQ to XML the correct way is to use cast instead of `Parse`. And in general for XML it's better to use `XmlConvert` methods, otherwise you have to always pass `CultureInfo.InvariantInfo` to every `Parse` call which you can easily forget (as you did :)

Comment: @IvanStoev why is culture info needed to parse an `int`?

Comment: Because XML should always use invariant culture. That's what `XMLConvert` is encapsulating, and also `XElement` casts. See for instance http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml.Linq and http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml/System/Xml/XmlConvert.cs,41a562543a0a2ccd

Answer (score 1):

Here is the correct LINQ to XML syntax:

```
Aim = item.Elements("Aim").ToDictionary(
    e => (string)e.Element("Type"),
    e => new Stat((int)e.Element("Value"), (int)e.Element("Last")))
```