# C# compile errors depending on the PC

Tags: c#, compiler-errors

I'm able to compile a C# project in my PC but my colleague has compilation errors when trying to compile the same project in his PC. Despite we are working with different VS versions (VS12 & VS15), .NET version and project configuration are the same.

Project compile on VS15 but not in VS12.

Both PCs are W7 and .NET 4.5.2 (my colleague has updated his version for this project).

Build error comes from a struct:

```
    public struct CommandMessage
    {
        public string RawMsg { get; set; }
        public string MsgId { get; set; }
        public string MsgBody { get; set; }
        public string[] MsgParams { get; set; }

        public CommandMessage(string rawMsg, string msgId, 
                              string msgBody, string[] msgParams)
        {
            RawMsg = rawMsg;
            MsgId = msgId;
            MsgBody = msgBody;
            MsgParams = msgParams;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "CommandMessage<<" + MsgId + ">> : <" + MsgBody + ">";
        }
    }
```

And this the error:

> CS0843: Backing field for automatically implemented property 
>   CommandMessage.RawMsg' must be fully assigned before control is returned to 
>   the caller. Consider calling the default constructor from a constructor 
>   initializer.

Error is repeated for every property in struct (RawMsg, MsgId, MsgBody, MsgParams)

Error is very easy to fix, just add `: this()`on constructor:

```
public CommandMessage(string rawMsg, string msgId, 
                      string msgBody, string[] msgParams) : this ()
    {
        ...
    }
```

But I'm not able to find why this error comes in one PC and not in another...some idea?

Comment: They are using different compiler versions, which *usually* means they have different versions of .NET/VS installed. This change was new in C# 6 or C# 7 You could *try* running `csc /version` at the command line - however, VS doesn't actually use `csc` (it talks to the compiler services directly), so this might still be misleading

Comment: It might matter whether you have VS2015 _and_ VS2017 installed.

Comment: @HenkHolterman OP mentioned that both systems have VS2015 and .net 4.5.2

Comment: @sachin - yes, but they said nothing about VS2017.

Comment: Compare the following setting on the working and the non-working PC: `Project Properties -> Build -> Advanced -> Language version`. What do you see in the drop-down list of language versions? Is it the same on both PCs?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Struct constructor: "fields must be fully assigned before control is returned to the caller."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534960/struct-constructor-fields-must-be-fully-assigned-before-control-is-returned-to)

Comment: @MatthewWatson In both PCs is "Default"

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong, we have using different VS versions, 2012 and 2015. Nevertheless, we are using the same compiler version...there is something extra to configure?

Comment: @miguialberto You didn't answer my question: I didn't ask what the setting for Language Version was, I asked what options are in the drop-down list. (If the option itself is set to "Default" then what you actually get will be the highest version available in the dropdown list - which may well differ between the two installations.)

Comment: @MatthewWatson They are not the same. In my PC there is until C# 6 but my colleague has only until C# 5. Could it be the problem?

Comment: @miguialberto Yep that's the issue - On your PC it's compiling using C#6 and on his it's using C#5.  Try changing it to C#6 explicitly on his PC. (VS2015 defaults to C#5, and VS2017 defaults to C#6)

Comment: @MatthewWatson Thank you for the solution!