# C# constructor with new and get integer

Tags: c#

This is a structure on Unity 5.5.0 I'm pretty new to c# and do not understand properties and structures well.

This gives an error on assigning during `this.X`.

I'm assuming that you can't change values on a structure and the keyword this refers to the structure's property

> Backing field for automatically implemented property 'Point.X' must be fully assigned before control is returned to the caller. Consider calling the default constructor from a constructor initializer. (CS0843) (Assembly-CSharp) [LN 15]
>
> The 'this' object cannot be used before all of its fields are assigned to (CS0188) (Assembly-CSharp) [LN 16]

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public struct Point 
{

    // Don't undertstand why "public int X, Y" works fine but not this        
    public int X { get; set; }

    public int Y { get; set; }

    //public int X,Y;

    public Point(int x, int y) 
    { 
        // LN 15
        this.X=x;
        this.Y=y;
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Struct constructor: "fields must be fully assigned before control is returned to the caller."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534960/struct-constructor-fields-must-be-fully-assigned-before-control-is-returned-to)

Comment: Try changing `public Point(int x, int y)` to `public Point(int x, int y) : this()`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Hopefully the link above will help answer your question and give you the ideas you need to solve the problem. Note that I found this link by copying the error message into a google search. This is often a very quick way to solve such problems.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is an oddity of some versions of C#; the compiler sometimes does not correctly detect that the structure has been fully initialized on all code paths through the constructor.

The fix is to say

```
public Point(int x, int y) : this()  // default initialization
{ 
  this.X = x;
  this.Y = y;
}
```

which tells the compiler "the fields are initialized to their default values before they are initialized in the constructor".

This was a bit of a failure of language design when we did C# 3; it's by no means clear that this is what you have to do. Sorry about that.

Since I have your attention, let's address this other point you raised:

> I'm assuming that you can't change values on a structure

You *can* change values on a structure, but you *should not*.  Structures should be:

- small
- logically values
- immutable

So my advice would be to **make the setters private** (with `private set;`)

You've made a mutable point structure, which is a bad practice.  Make an immutable point structure, and treat them as immutable mathematical objects, not as collections of variables.

Also:

> the keyword this refers to the structure's property

The keyword `this` is an *alias to the variable which holds the value of the structure instance*.  This is subtle; let me give you an example.  If we say:

```
Point a = new Point(1, 2);
```

that means:

- Make a new temporary storage variable the size of one point.
- Invoke the two-argument constructor, making `this` an alias for that temporary storage variable, and copying 1 and 2 into formal parameters x and y.
- After the constructor returns, copy the value in the temporary variable into variable `a`.

Now, you might note that it seems like it would be more efficient to do:

- Invoke the two-argument constructor, making `this` an alias for `a`, and so on.

And it would be more efficient; that is called a *copy elision optimization* and C# does it *when it knows that it is impossible for the user to notice a difference*. (Challenge: construct a C# program where the user could determine whether copy elision was used or not; C# will *not* copy-elide in such a program!)

Similarly if you then did:

```
struct Point
{
   ... constructors, whatever ...
   public double DistanceFromOrigin()
   {
     return Math.Sqrt(this.X * this.X + this.Y * this.Y);
   }
```

When you call `a.DistanceFromOrigin()`, `this` becomes an alias for `a`; they are *the same variable* just with two different names.

This is *not* how reference types work.  In a reference type, `this` is a *copy* of the *reference*. In a value type, `this` is an *alias to a variable*.

These are subtle points.

Comment: 13 minutes after Eric posted a challenge and still no solution proposed 8| must be a tough one...

Comment: @vc74: It's not that hard. Give it a shot!

Comment: Does the solution involve capturing `this` during construction?

Comment: @vc74: That's not the example I was thinking of but there might be something there! Rules for capturing `this` as an outer variable of a lambda are interesting in a struct because you cannot capture a ref.

Comment: My 2nd gut reaction to this question was to think of unsafe code, but you can do whatever you want in unsafe code, so I figured there was a more interesting solution.  My first gut reaction was to think threading, because any time someone mentions the compiler "noticing something," I mentally add, "warning: the compiler doesn't notice multi-threading."

Comment: As you note, unsafe code can in fact do *anything*, so it is not that interesting to show that unsafe code does something.

Comment: @vc74: Spoiler alert in the next comment I'll discuss your proposal.

Comment: vc74's idea that capture has something to do with it is good. For example: `struct S{ private int x; private int y; public S(int x, int y, Action a) { this.x = x; a(); this.y = y; } public override string ToString() => (y > 0).ToString(); }` Now suppose we have `S s = default(S); s = new S(1, 2, ()=>{}); s = new S(3, 4, ()=>Console.WriteLine(s);` Now we can tell if the copy is elided. If it is, and the third assignment to `s` is mutating `s` directly, then `y` is `2` and so this prints `True`.  If the copy is not elided then `y` is still zero in the temp.

Comment: So we now know: the compiler does not elide the copy if the local in question is a closed-over outer variable of a lambda.  But there is an even simpler example that would illustrate if a copy elision happens.

Comment: Change the constructor to `public S(int x, int y, bool b) { this.x = x; if (b) throw new Exception(); this.y = y; }` and the call site to `S s = default(S); try { s = new S(1, 2, false); s = new S(3, 4, true); } finally { Console.WriteLine(s); }` We now know if the copy is elided because if it is, again, the throw happens when x is 3 and y is 2, so this prints true.  If it is not, then x is 3 and y is 0.

Comment: So we now know: the compiler does not elide the copy if the local declaration and the assignment are not in the same "try" block. If I recall correctly, that's it; in other cases, locals are passed as `ref this` in the constructor because you can't tell the difference without a debugger.

Comment: I suppose `x` is unnecessary in those examples. Those examples came from a more complex example that I used to illustrate how copy elision could violate invariants if it happens in the wrong place.

Comment: Thanks for your enlightening comments Eric! I suspected "external code" had to be executed during construction but didn't find concrete examples like yours. For anyone interested, I created fiddles for Eric's examples: https://dotnetfiddle.net/SU38Qr https://dotnetfiddle.net/RVPMco

Comment: On a different topic, I had to replace `finally` with `catch` for `Console.WriteLine(s);` to execute otherwise the finally block does not seem to execute. I guess it's because it's in `Main` directly but I was not aware of this behavior. Does it mean that in a console application you should put your `try/finally` code in another method called by Main?

Comment: @vc74: Have you got a try block in main with an uncaught exception and a finally block?  In that situation it is *implementation-defined* what happens. When there is an uncaught exception, the program is permitted to do anything, and "run the finally block" is included in "anything", as is "don't run the finally block".

Comment: Thanks, I think the latter was the option in my case (Console/.net 4.6). I guess the rule of thumb is to move Main try/finally block to a separate method otherwise the finally block might not be called in case of exception.

Comment: @vc74: No, you're not getting what I'm saying. It doesn't matter where in the program the try-finally is.  What matters is whether the exception is ever caught or not!  If an exception is never caught then the runtime can do *anything*. It can terminate the process immediately, it can start a debugger, it can phone home to Microsoft describing the crash, it can run finally blocks, it can not run finally blocks, it can do **anything you could write a program to do**.  If you don't like that then **catch every exception that is thrown**. Uncaught exceptions are pure concentrated evil.