# What is the difference between a struct constructor with `this()` at the end and another without?

Tags: c#, struct, constructor

Let's say we have these two structs...

```
public struct Example
{
    public int Number { get; set; }

    public Example(int Number)
    {
        Number = number;
    }
}
```

and:

```
public struct Example
{
    public int Number { get; set; }

    public Example(int number) : this()
    {
        Number = number;
    }
}
```

You can see that there's a struct with a constructor with `**this()**` at the end and another without.

What is the difference between the two?

Comment: The c'tor in the second example calls the empty c'tor, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009013/call-one-constructor-from-another

Comment: Worth noting that this syntax can be required in some versions of the C# compiler. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52189683/c-sharp-constructor-with-new-and-get-integer#comment91329132_52189683)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Calling this() initializes all fields with zeroes. C# compiler requires all struct fields to be initialized in constructor. So if you want to specify not all fields you should call this().

Will not compile:

```
struct A
{
    public int field1;
    public string field2;

     public A(string str)
     {
         field2 = str;
     }
}
```

Gives:

> Error  CS0171  Field 'A.field1' must be fully assigned before control is returned to the caller ...

Is OK:

```
struct A
{
    public int field1;
    public string field2;

    public A(string str) : this()
    {
        field2 = str;
    }
}
```

Weird, but still OK:

```
struct A
{
    public int field1;
    public string field2;

    public A(string str)
    {
        this = new A(); // in structs 'this' is assignable
        field2 = str;
    }
}
```

or

```
struct A
{
    public int field1;
    public string field2;

    public A(string str)
    {
        this = default(A); // in structs 'this' is assignable
        field2 = str;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

UPDATED

**For a class**:

The difference is that the constructor that calls `this()` will also call the class's constructor that takes no arguments. So, for example, if this were your class:

```
public class Example
{
    public int Number { get; set; }

    public Example(int number) : this()
    {
        Number = number;
    }
    public Example()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello");
    }
}
```

Then including `this()` would also print "Hello". This is a way you can chain constructors together, for code reuse.

**For a struct**:

You cannot add an empty constructor in a struct, so adding `this()` does not provide any benefit. Thanks to vendettamit for waking up my tired brain.

Comment: **CS0568 Structs cannot contain explicit parameterless constructors.**

Comment: Depends on the version of C#, in C# 5.0 you can define a parameter-less struct constructor.

Answer (score 2):

In your example, there is no behavioral change as `this()` calls the parameter-less constructor for the struct which is not defined.

Note that in C# 6.0 and newer you cannot [re-define](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333829/why-cant-i-define-a-default-constructor-for-a-struct-in-net) a struct's parameter-less constructor, so if you do:

```
public struct Example
{
    public Example() // compile error in c# 6.0 and up
    {
    }
}
```

You'll get a compile error. More details [here](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/1029).

In older versions of C# you can re-define the parameter-less constructor which means you may inject extra behavior in your parameterized constructor by modifying the parameter-less one.

Apart from this, there may be a theoretical performance hit due to the extra IL code generated for the `this()` constructor:

```
Example..ctor:
IL_0000:  ldarg.0     
IL_0001:  initobj     UserQuery.Example
IL_0007:  nop         
IL_0008:  ldarg.0     
IL_0009:  ldarg.1     
IL_000A:  call        UserQuery+Example.set_Number
IL_000F:  nop         
IL_0010:  ret
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference. `this()` would call to a parameterless constructor, which is a must for structs by definition, which will not do anything unless you redefine it and customize its behavior. In case of `struct`s you are not allowed to define your own parameterless constructor; with `class`es you can though.

However, please note that constructor chaining is a handy tool to DRY in a complicated construction scenarios: i.e. when object exposes numerous constructors with different parameters.

Comment: what do you mean by "structs by definition"

Comment: There are `struct`s and `class`es in C#, see the docs for details.