# What's wrong about the first 2 public times?

Tags: c#

For school I need to make an exercise, but none of the teachers want to help me because we work in a group together, and I'm way further then them, so I need to wait until they are as far as me. Could one of you help me please? This is the first time working with this type of C#. They never even showed us how to work with it and I don't know what to do.

```
using System;

namespace Tracks
{
    public class Class1
    {
        private int id;
        private string name;
        private string artist;
        private string albumSource;
        private Category style;
        private Time length;

        enum Category
        {

            Ambient = 0,
            Blues = 1,
            Country = 2,
            Disco = 3,
            Electro = 4,
            Hardcore = 5,
            HardRocck = 6,
            HeavyMetal = 7,
            Hiphop = 8,
            Jazz = 9,
            Jumpstyle = 10,
            KLassiek = 11,
            Latin = 12,
            Other = 13,
            Pop = 14,
            Punk = 15,
            Reggae = 16,
            Rock = 17,
            Soul = 18,
            Trance = 19,
            Techno = 20,
        }
        public struct Time
        {
            public int s, m, h;

            public Time(int s1)
            {
                s = s1;
            }
            public Time(int s1, int m1)
            {
                s = s1;
                m = m1;
            }
            public Time(int s1, int m1, int h1)
            {
                s = s1;
                m = m1;
                h = h1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And what´s your question? Do you get any error or unexpected results?

Comment: Can you be more descriptive in the title and also about the issue and the expected behavior.

Comment: You could improve your question by removing information about the school and adding information about what you want to achieve with the code and what is the actual problem you are having.

Comment: Hi, may want to take few minutes and read [ask]. Then [edit] your question to follow the guide lines. Take your time explain use the context, What you are trying to achieve? What you imagine, the way you want to call it? What the expected result, do you have any case to illustrate the issue?

Comment: you may want to hit the [tour] page too. As the first sentence state : "_Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for **professional** and **enthusiast programmers**._". See no evil in the feedback, it's just feed back. Stay professional.

Comment: Mark as duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534960/struct-constructor-fields-must-be-fully-assigned-before-control-is-returned-to

Comment: For the record: a: public fields are a **terrible** idea, and b: mutable structs are a **terrible** idea. This is a mutable struct with public fields! `public readonly struct Time { public int Seconds {get;} public int Minutes {get;} public int Hours {get;} public Time(int seconds, int minutes = 0, int hours = 0) { Hours = hours; Minutes = minutes; Seconds = seconds; /* TODO: add range validation */ } }` - done, safe, tidy. Or even better: just use `TimeSpan`. Side note: you could do it all with a single integer and modulo arithmetic (which is ultimately what `TimeSpan` does)

Comment: Unrelated: If you have the time (being far ahead of the other teammates) you should rather put some effort in rethinking this design and learning how things are done in C#. For example: Is it a good idea to have the `enum` defined here? Is it a good idea to have that `Time` struct defined here? Is it a good idea to use a struct? Is it a good idea to make your own `Time`  struct? Is it a good idea to name Class1 just that? ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `Time` is a `struct` all the fields need to be initialized in the constructor. Change your first two constructors to the following:

```
public Time(int s1)
{
    s = s1;
    m = h = 0;
}

public Time(int s1, int m1)
{
    s = s1;
    m = m1;
    h = 0;
}
```

or even better define them as this:

```
public Time(int s1) : this(s1, 0, 0) {}
public Time(int s1, int m1) : this (s1, m1, 0) {}
public Time(int s1, int m1, int h1)
{
    s = s1;
    m = m1;
    h = h1;
}
```

this way you have the alignments only in one place.

Comment: For simple default value like this, optional parametermay be better.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to have a constructor that you can call with default value, you can simply :

```
public Time(int s1, int m1 = 0, int h1 = 0)
{
    s = s1;
    m = m1;
    h = h1;
}
```

You will be able to call it like:

```
Time( 1 );
Time( 1, 2 );
Time( 1, 2, 3 );
```